# Execution stops after await Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

```
const tooling = require("tooling")
module.export = {
    run : async function(){
        let arr = [["aaa"],["bbb", "ccc"]]
        let promises = arr[0].map(id => this.installPackage(id))
        await Promise.all(promises)
        console.log("Finished Installing")
    }

    installPackage : async function(id){
        let requestId = await tooling.create(id)
        return this.pollInstall(requestId)
    }

    pollInstall : function(id){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            tooling.retrieve(id).then(resp => {
                if(resp.Status === "SUCCESS") return resp.Status
                else setTimeout(() => {this.pollInstall(id)}, 5000)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

With the above code snippet anything after *await Promise.all(promises)* dose not execute and no errors are being thrown as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be the case? or would be able to prod me in the direction of the issue.

Comment: What is `err[0]` in `promises` array supposed to be? Is it typo?

Comment: yup, sorry. that was supposed to be arr[0]

Comment: `arr[0].map` returns `'aaa'`, is it what you expect it to return?

Comment: it returns the promise created at `pollInstall` does it not?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase it: `arr[0].map(id => this.installPackage(id))` returns `[this.installPackage('aaa')]`, nothing more. Are you sure `this` is what you think it is? I think `run()` doesn't have `installPackage` function in `this`, Try `arr[0].map(id => installPackage(id))`.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet to be a bit more clear. To answer the question, Yes `installPackage('aaa')` is part of `this`. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and forgetting to resolve the promise. Instead, write

```
pollInstall: async function(id) {
    const resp = await tooling.retrieve(id);
    if (resp.Status === "SUCCESS") {
        return resp.Status;
    } else {
        await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 5000); });
        return this.pollInstall(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `pollInstall function` return a `Promise` which is not resolving, try this:

```
pollInstall : function(id){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            tooling.retrieve(id).then(resp => {
                if(resp.Status === "SUCCESS") return resolve(resp.Status)
                else setTimeout(() => {this.pollInstall(id)}, 5000)
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. it just executes the promise then stops

Comment: @Ayoub It's just still missing `resolve` in the `else` case. And in the case that `retrieve` rejects.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi didn't notice that `resolve` is needed in else